# CSS divs: margin:auto on vertical for IE7

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="wr">
    <div id="unknownWidthAndHeight">should be centered on both sides</div>
</div>

#wr {
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#unknownWidthAndHeight{
    display:table;
    height:30px;
    margin:auto;    
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdTGZ/2/

Need such support for IE7 without `display:table` etc. and without `<table>` usage.

Comment: this question gets asked about once a day: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+centering+ie7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ If you want to **vertical center** on IE7 try this technique using three divs :
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Ps : You'll always need to **set the container height**.

2/ The element that you want to **horizontal center** must have a `width` and `margin:0 auto;` otherwise you can try `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

#wr {
    display: block
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 100px;  /* must be the same as height */
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:50px;

}
#unknownWidthAndHeight{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wr">
            <div id="unknownWidthAndHeight">should be centered on both sides</div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```